# How can I connect to remote session and get the server output on my local

Tags: linux, terminal, session

So I have a remote server in cloud running my application, when I need to test / soak test I run ./gradlew- on my local. which runs a script > connect to vm - my application > and start the test on my vm. I can see the ./gradle output on my local terminal so when the test ends, server gives back the results to my local through gradle session. But if i lost the connection to my vm during long test or lost internet for some reason, the gradle session gets disconnected and exit, This doesnt give me the result automatically in my local. Is there a way to get back that gradle session if i connect to internet again.

Comment: Use `tmux` or `screen` on the remote host, if possible. That will allow you to reconnect to an existing session if the connection goes down. I don't know how it plays with Gradle though.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know the specifics about Gradle but the following is a generic approach that one can use to execute a remote process, regardless of a lost connection:

- [ssh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell) into the remote machine
- (tmux/screen) and/or nohup a process
- (detach from the ssh session)
- [scp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_copy)/rsync the results from the remote server to your local machine

Bellow is a generic example of what is described above:

```
local> $ ssh user@remoteHostName
remote> $ nohup ./command &
...closed session...
local> $ scp user@remoteHostName:/results/directory/result.txt .
```

Although this is not exactly what you are doing, it looks like what your command is doing. And this knowledge will help you debug any problems and even avoid rerunning the tasks again (like if your connection dropped while you were downloading the results).

You can look at wikipedia/google for more information about all those tools. Unfortunately as I have low reputation I cannot put more than 2 links :(